# When is the intersection of Perfect sets also perfect?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\def\N{\mathbf{N}}$
$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
I know examples where the intersection of perfect sets sometimes yield in a perfect and sometimes does not, for instance:

1. The Cantor set construction involves the countably-infinite intersection of perfect sets, resulting in a perfect set - the cantor set.
2. The perfect sets of the form $\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right]$, when intersected through $n\in \N$, yields $\left\{0 \right\}$, which isn't perfect.

So my question is, **can we strengthen our hypothesis by adding some extra condition(s) that *does* guarantee that the (arbitrary) intersection of perfect sets is also perfect?**

**Remark.** *As far as possible*, stay in the real numbers $\R$, or if you have to, $\R^n$ . I have little to no knowledge about other metric spaces/other topological spaces and how they work.

Comment: Perhaps first do it for the intersection of two sets.  In $\mathbb R$ we know that $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ are perfect, but their intersection $\{1\}$ is not.

Comment: I think we'd have to somehow locally assure that the boundary points don't get intersected with boundary points, so maybe some condition like, for all $x\in A\cap B$ and open $x\in U$ we have $\text{int}(A\cap B\cap U) \neq\emptyset$ would work.

Comment: Stupid answers: *1.  The intersection of a family of perfect sets is perfect iff it is nonempty and contains no isolated points.*  Or, *2.  The intersection of a family of perfect sets is perfect iff every point is a point of condensation.*  It is hard to imagine there is another answer equivalent to these that would be of interest.  Maybe someone has an idea though.